# Remote PowerShell Exchange: Using windows forms input and passing to remote Exchange Session

Tags: winforms, powershell, exchange-server, powershell-remoting

First post, apologies for any formatting issues, couldn't find a direct way to insert PowerShell code and the JavaScript Language insert looked the closest.

I have created a tool that enables remote PowerShell connections to various Exchange servers in an environment. This tool uses windows forms for a GUI and has various options that a user selects and inputs. I have the GUI controls all working properly and am able to connect to the remote Exchange servers without issue. The Exchange environments are 2010, 2013 on-prem and O365.

I’m trying to utilize more user input to make the remote session as hands-off as possible, and I’m running into a problem with passing custom functions or commands to the remote session AFTER successfully connecting.

The desired behavior: have the contents of the text box be used as part of a command to search message-trackinglogs on the transport servers. Within the function Connect-Exchange, I have the function Message-Subject that performs the search.

I have searched around and tried various methods, but can’t seem to get any of them to work in the desired manner. I’m looking for the connection to be made and session established, and then have the command run. I’m not sure if that’s possible, so I created a function that would hopefully run automatically after the session establishes, and then have the user just type the function call.
I believe the issue lies around lines 169-171 with Import-PSSession and Invoke-Command.

Ultimately, I’d like the GUI to be able to have all the attributes of the MessageTracking search captured and the command ran automatically without any further user input.

Can this be done?

Also, the way I have it setup might not be the most practical, so I’m open to advice if there’s a better way.

Thanks

```js
##
Connect Remote Exchange PowerShell


## Function Input Box-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -

function Connect - Exchange {

  Add - Type - AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
  Add - Type - AssemblyName System.Drawing



  ## Form Code-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --


  ##Form details

  $form = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
  $form.Text = "Connect to Remote Exchange"
  $form.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
  $form.Size = New - Object System.Drawing.Size(500, 330)
  $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
  $form.TopMost = $True
  $form.AutoSize = $True
  $form.FormBorderStyle = 'Fixed3D'
  $form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"


  ##
  Radio Buttons-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --


  ##Group Box
  for Radio Buttons

  $GroupBox = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox
  $GroupBox.Location = New - Object System.Drawing.Point(40, 30)
  $GroupBox.size = New - Object System.Drawing.Size(400, 180)
  $GroupBox.Text = 'Select the desired domain and press "OK" to connect:'

  ##
  Radio Button 1

  $radioButton1 = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
  $radioButton1.Text = "Exchange 2010"
  $radioButton1.Location = New - Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 40)
  $radioButton1.Size = New - Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 20)
  $radioButton1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
  $radioButton1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
  $radioButton1.TabIndex = 0

  ## Radio Button 2

  $radioButton2 = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
  $radioButton2.Text = "Exchange 2010"
  $radioButton2.Location = New - Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 70)
  $radioButton2.Size = New - Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 20)
  $radioButton2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
  $radioButton2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
  $radioButton2.TabIndex = 1

  ## Radio Button 3

  $radioButton3 = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
  $radioButton3.Text = "Exhcange 2013"
  $radioButton3.Location = New - Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 100)
  $radioButton3.Size = New - Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 20)
  $radioButton3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
  $radioButton3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
  $radioButton3.TabIndex = 2

  ## Radio Button 4

  $radioButton4 = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
  $radioButton4.Text = "Office 365"
  $radioButton4.Location = New - Object System.Drawing.Point(20, 130)
  $radioButton4.Size = New - Object System.Drawing.Size(350, 20)
  $radioButton4.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
  $radioButton4.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True
  $radioButton4.TabIndex = 3

  ## Text Box

  $textBox = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
  $textBox.Location = New - Object System.Drawing.Point(515, 40)
  $textBox.Size = New - Object System.Drawing.Size(300)
  $textBox.WordWrap = $True
  $textLabel1 = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $textLabel1.Location = New - Object System.Drawing.Point(300, 40)
  $textLabel1.AutoSize = $True
  $textLabel1.Text = "Enter Message Subject without Quotes:"

  ##
  OK / Cancel Buttons-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --


    ##OK Button

  $okButton = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $okButton.Location = New - Object System.Drawing.Point(130, 230)
  $okButton.Size = New - Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 40)
  $okButton.Text = "OK"
  $okButton.TabIndex = 4
  $okButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK

  ## Cancel Button

  $cancelButton = New - Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $cancelButton.Location = New - Object System.Drawing.Point(255, 230)
  $cancelButton.Size = New - Object System.Drawing.Size(100, 40)
  $cancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
  $cancelButton.TabIndex = 5
  $cancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel


  ## Actions / Misc.-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

    ##Get Text Box Input

  $messageSubject = $textBox.Text

  ## Search Transport Log Function

  function Message - Subject {
    Set - Variable $messageSubject = $textBox.Text - Scope 1
    $i = 0
    $transportServers = get - transportserver
    foreach($transportserver in $transportServers) {
      $trackingLogs = Get - MessageTrackingLog - MessageSubject $messageSubject - resultsize unlimited - Start "Feb 27 2018 00:00:00" - EventId Deliver | Select - Object {
        $_.Recipients
      }
      $i++
      Write - Progress - Activity "Checking Transport Logs" - status "Server: $i of $($transportServers.Count) " - PercentComplete(($i / $transportServers.Count) * 100)
    }

    $trackingLogs | Export - Csv "C:\test.csv" - NoTypeInformation
  }

  ##
  Add Form and GroupBox Radio Button Controls

  $form.Controls.AddRange(@($GroupBox, $textBox, $textLabel1, $okButton, $cancelButton))
  $GroupBox.Controls.AddRange(@($radioButton1, $radioButton2, $radioButton3, $radioButton4))


  ## Form Accept and Cancel Options Assigned to OK / Cancel Buttons

  $form.AcceptButton = $okButton
  $form.CancelButton = $cancelButton

  ## Activate and Show Form

  $form.Add_Shown({
    $form.Activate()
  })

  $result = $form.ShowDialog()

  ## Credential input

  ## Connection Commands


  ## Script block actions-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -


  if ($result - eq "OK") {##
    Check radio button status
    if ($radioButton1.Checked) {
      $response1 = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Connect to", "Confirmation", 4)
      if ($response1 - eq "Yes") {
        $creds1 = Get - Credential - Message 'Enter  Exchange credentials:'
        $session1 = New - PSSession - ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange - ConnectionUri "http://" - Credential $creds1 - Authentication Kerberos
        Import - PSSession $session1
        Invoke - Command - Session $session1 - ScriptBlock $ {
          function: Message - Subject
        }
        $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = $creds1.UserName + " (Exchange 2010) "
        $host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "Black"
        $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Red"
        Clear - Host
      } else {
        $form.close()
      }
    }
    if ($radioButton2.Checked) {
      $response2 = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Connect to", "Confirmation", 4)
      if ($response2 - eq "Yes") {
        $creds2 = Get - Credential - Message 'Enter  Exchange credentails:'
        $session2 = New - PSSession - ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange - ConnectionUri "http://fqdn.domain/PowerShell" - Credential  $creds2 - Authentication Kerberos
        Import - PSSession $session2
        $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = $creds2.UserName + " (Exchange 2010) "
        $host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "Black"
        $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Red"
        Clear - Host
      } else {
        $form.Close()
      }
    }
    if ($radioButton3.Checked) {
      $response3 = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Connect to", "Confirmation", 4)
      if ($response3 - eq "Yes") {
        $creds3 = Get - Credential - Message 'Enter  Exchange credentails:'
        $session3 = New - PSSession - ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange - ConnectionUri "http://fqdn.domain/PowerShell" - Credential $creds3 - Authentication Kerberos
        Import - PSSession $session3
        $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = $creds3.UserName + " (Exchange 2013) "
        $host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "Black"
        $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Red"
        Clear - Host
      } else {
        $form.Close()
      }
    }
    if ($radioButton4.Checked) {
      $response4 = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Connect to ", "Confirmation", 4)
      if ($response4 - eq "Yes") {
        $rcreds3 = Get - Credential - Message 'Enter  Exchange credentails:'
        $session4 = New - PSSession - ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange - ConnectionUri "https://ps.outlook.com/powershell-liveid/" - Credential $creds4 - Authentication Basic - AllowRedirection
        Import - PSSession $session4 - DisableNameChecking

        $session4 = New - PSSession - ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange - ConnectionUri "https://ps.compliance.protection.outlook.com/powershell-liveid/" - Credential $creds4 - Authentication Basic - AllowRedirection
        Import - PSSession $session4 - AllowClobber - DisableNameChecking
        $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = $creds4.UserName + " (Exchange Online + Compliance Center) "
        $host.ui.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "Black"
        $host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = "Red"#
        Clear - Host
      } else {
        $form.close()
      }
    }
  } else {
    if ($result - eq "Cancel") {
      [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Cancel and exit?", "Confirmation", 4)
    }
  }


}##
End Connect - Exchange Function


## Call the Function-- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --


Connect - Exchange
```

Comment: In one part of your code, you're creating a `New-PSSession`, then importing the session, then doing an `Invoke-Command` on that session.  I'd recommend skipping the import, and explicitly use the invocations when you want to do something remotely. This will make the lifetime of the session super clear, and allow cumulative effects of calls through the lifetime of the session.  e.g. You can `Invoke-Command -Session $session1 { function myNewFunction { ... }}` to create a new function in that scope and then refer to it later.  (If that's truly what you want to do.)

Comment: Also consider if you truly want separate sessions per radio button choice, or to just create one (or a few) and re-use them.

Comment: @MatthewWetmore thank you for the tip, I saw that a few places, but was under the impression that `Import-Session` was necessary. I'll give that a shot asap. Another concern I had was passing the variable from the text box between functions properly. Do I have it passed properly so the `$messageSubject` variable will persist in the remote session?

The different radio buttons represent different Exchange environments on separate domains. The ultimate goal would be to have a session run searches against all my environments, but I'm not sure that it's a possibility at this point.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're getting several issues going in this question at once.  StackOverflow is meant to focus on one topic at a time with the smallest possible answerable examples that represent a class of problem.  I'd recommend breaking this up into a couple questions like "how do I pass a variable into a new-possession and re-use it" and/or "how do I call the same commands on multiple computers at once?". Those are probably already answered, but you may be able to simplify your questions and get to the heart of the problem.  P.S. Try invoke-command -session $S { $using:myvar }